# Scala REPL hanging indefinitely when calling map(f).sum on Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, rdd, read-eval-print-loop

I find the following simple example hangs indefinitely for me in the Scala REPL (`sbt console`):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000000)
val n = rdd.map(_ + 1).sum
```

However, the following works just fine:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
val sc = spark.sparkContext
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000000)
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(_ + 1)
val n = rdd2.sum
```

I'm very confused by this, and was hoping somebody had an explanation... assuming they can reproduce the 'issue'.

This is basically just the example provided on the [Almond kernel's Spark documentation page](https://almond.sh/docs/usage-spark), and it does work just fine in Jupyter using the Almond kernel.  Also, `sbt "runMain Main"` works just fine for the following:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql._

object Main extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  val sc = spark.sparkContext
  val rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000000)
  val n = rdd.map(_ + 1).sum

  println(s"\n\nn: $n\n\n")
  
  spark.stop
}
```

For completeness, I'm using a very simple `build.sbt` file, which looks as follows:

```scala
name := """sparktest"""

scalaVersion := "2.12.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.6"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.6"
```

Comment: Code you provided in the first block works just fine for me on my local `spark-shell`

Comment: I didn't try `spark-shell`, but I was assuming this was only happening specifically via `sbt console` for some reason.  I don't have `spark-shell` on the same machine, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a bunch of errors like the following when I killed the console:

```sh
08:53:36 ERROR Executor:70 - Exception in task 2.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 2): Could not initialize class $line3.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$
```

This led me to:

[Lambda in REPL (using object-wrappers) + concurrency = deadlock #9076](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/9076)

It seems that my problem is this same thing and is specific to Scala 2.12.  Adding the following line to `build.sbt` seems to be the accepted workaround:

```scala
scalacOptions += "-Ydelambdafy:inline"
```